# r count values in one column based on another column

Tags: r

So we say that we are using a Movies dataset. We have 300 film names and each name has a release year. How do I count the number of films in a particular year?

```
movies.df %>% 
  count(film, year)
```

Comment: You can do `sum(movies.df$year == 2020)` to count movies in 2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, thewal , you didnt show an example , and i am just suggesting you do the following which might be of some help

```
movies.df %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(n=n())
```

This will count the number of films in a year

Comment: I used count instead of summarise

Comment: I was just wondering, can I have just the values of films in the result. With this code it shows n and nn. n being film count, nn being film count per year?

Answer (score 0):

You can try...

```
library(dplyr)
g <- group_by(movies.df, year)
summarise(g, length(year))
```